# wordpress navigation help

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a website that consists of the following areas,

- Home
- About Us
- Project Management
- Small Works
- Testimonials
- Contact Us
- **Current Projects**

My issue is that I can display a navigation bar fine, however the Current Projects is not acutally a page, it is more of a category that has a collection of posts, how can I add this to my nav bar, so that when a user clicks to see the current projects, it shows the titles of the posts that are in the current_projects category? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this and the users will be pointed to /category/current-projects

```
<?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
```

**A more in-depth:**

```
<ul>
 <?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li='); ?> // This will output all pages.
 <?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&depth=1'); ?> // This will output all categories.
</ul>
```

You can exclude categories from showing by adding **&exclude=5,6,7** (5,6,7 being the categories ID's that you want to exclude. or **&include=3,2,1**)

It generates HTML like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" title="">Page One</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Page Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Page Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Page For</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="">Category One</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can I use that along side, `<?php wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li='); ?>`

Comment: Sorry one more question, is it possible to have have the the Category Placed within the navigation menu and not just put on the end? something like - Home - Category 1 - About us etc

Comment: You can add home manualy, then add the wp_list_categories function. Like this <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('home') ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Homepage">Home</a></li>